# Terraria End Game

Tags: terraria

What is the end goal of Terraria? More specifically, at what action taken / boss defeated / item acquired can you say that you've beaten the game?

I know it's a sandbox game, and thus doesn't really have an "end goal," but it still feels like there could be. What is it? Or, what would it be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no single official end goal. However, there are a few long-term goals the game sets:

- Fight all boss monsters (kind of the minimum thing you have to do before you can claim to have beaten the game)
- Get/craft all equipment (requires fighting many bosses multiple times).
- Completely eliminate all corruption from the world (the Dryad wants you to do this, but it would be an incredible amount of repetitive work).
- Collect all [achievements](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Achievements).

And of course you can do all this in [mediumcore](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mediumcore_mode) or [hardcore](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hardcore_mode) for an extra challenge.

Apart from that, many players make up goals for themselves, often in the form of building elaborate structures.

Comment: I've actually cleared a map of Corruption/Crimson using the Clentaminator. It's not too hard, but you do have to keep re-visiting areas because you'll miss a block or two here and there, and they'll re-corrupt a large patch.